# ExtJS CheckboxGroup label wrap

Tags: extjs

I have a problem with checkboxes. So these checkboxes are in columns, and the longer labels wrap under their checkboxes. Is there any sollution to setting the column width to the longest label? It must be dynamic width. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something you can use to measure all the labels and apply the width of the widest one to all of them http://jsfiddle.net/Wr7Wr/1/

```
Ext.define('DynamicLabelFormPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    initComponent: function() {
        // Need to create a hidden field to measure the text
        var field = new Ext.form.field.Text({fieldLabel: 'Testing', value: 'whateves', renderTo: Ext.getBody(), hidden: true});
        var metrics = new Ext.util.TextMetrics(field.labelEl);
        var widths = Ext.Array.map(this.items, function(item) {
            // Need to acount for the : 
            return metrics.getWidth(item.fieldLabel + ":");
        });
        var maxWidth = Math.max.apply(Math, widths);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            this.items[i].labelWidth = maxWidth;
        }
        this.callParent();
    }
}
```

This would probably be better as a plugin, but it shows you what needs to be done

Comment: Oh, thx for advice, sorry, i forgot to tell these are boxLabels

Comment: @Eleanor The box labels do not have a fixed width, so if you don't want them to wrap, you need to make your container wider. If you provide an example of what the problem is, I can give it a shot

Comment: I added a css class and "white-space: nowrap;" can help me, but mow i need to change box label data :( and the container fieldset width to grow to checkboxgroup width...

Comment: @Eleanor I already told you I can try to help you if you create an example, if you're not willing to create an example, I'm not willing to keep guessing stuff to solve your problem.